# Unity WaitForSeconds Not Working?

Tags: c#, unity

I'm testing out WaitForSeconds

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Wait : MonoBehaviour {
private int time = 3;


void Start() {
    StartCoroutine(Example());
}

IEnumerator Example() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    print(":)");
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Does the print happen immediately or not at all?

Comment: It happens Immediately.

Comment: Why don't you just put it to Update and remove Time.DeltaTime from the variable "time" until it gets to 0 and then execute your code?

Comment: ???????????????????????????

Comment: I never put a time.delta time in my script

Comment: I have tested out your code, with a few debug log prints in there for good measure, and it all works as it should. I believe you might be under the impression that your co-routine will continue to repeat your Print() command, which is not the case. I will go into it more in an answer.

Comment: And here it's because, again, you don't show any research effort by not writing what you expected and only throwing a block of code at us; and you reply by '????????????????????‌​???????': it would have been preferable to use words.

Comment: @Alexandre Vaillancourt, a worded reply does follow..

Comment: @Timelord64 It does. The user was wondering why he was downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** In the example you give, `WaitForSeconds()` works perfectly fine. When tested, the code waits approximately 3 seconds, before providing the printed output. It is important to note that a co-routine does not deliberately repeat itself - you actually have to tell it to do so. *If repetition is your intention, scroll down to **Reiteration in Co-routines***.

### Testing the Code

I made a few changes to more accurately test your code, and found that it actually works as intended. While I made a few changes, the logic is original to your design:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float time = 3;                                                              

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CoroutineExample());
    }

    IEnumerator CoroutineExample()
    {
        Debug.Log("CoroutineExample started at " + Time.time.ToString() + "s");         

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        Debug.Log("Coroutine Iteration Successful at " + Time.time.ToString() + "s");   
    }
}
```

---

To address the small changes I made,

- I used `float time` instead of `int time`, but `int time` still works correctly. I used a floating point instead of an integer, because `WaitForSeconds()` is designed to take a `float`, not an `int`. In this context, it works it out pretty well, on its own. This is not always the case, and it is best practice to use the correct types whenever possible. If you really had to use an integer, you could also cast it as `(Float)time`, for example.
- I changed the `print()` function calls to `[Debug.Log()]`. Using the editor in Windows, it is easier to simply route debug script to the Debug.Log. At the end of the day, we get the same result; text-based feedback to confirm correct functionality. If you are unfamiliar with Debug.Log, you can find it's API reference [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html). I believe it works similar, if not identical, to `print()` but it is simply the way I was taught to perform debug output.
- I added a 'Debug.Log()' to the start of the co-routine, so we can confirm that the co-routine has initially started.
- I added `Time.time` to the format printed by `Debug.Log()`, in order to see the exact time stamps of each debug output.

---

When I run the code, this is what I get in my debug log:

[image: My debug log, showing successful WaitForSeconds() operation]

As you can see, the timing is not perfect; but we start the co-routine at 0 seconds, and see the final output after *approximately* 3 seconds. After the second `Debug.Log()` command, the co-routine reaches the end of the line, and nothing else is done.

### Reiteration in Co-routines

As mentioned, the code you supply offers nothing to tell the co-routine to reiterate. It will print ":)" once, and only once. That is because co-routines are not specifically designed for repetition - they are designed to allow you to perform a set function *over time*. While you can have a co-routine that repeats itself, you need to specifically tell it to.\

---

In your example, we can use a generic `while(true)` loop to tell the co-routine to repeat through the last 2 steps. Typically you would use a more specific loop to ensure the co-routine loops when it is suppose to, but `while(true)` is fine to demonstrate simple repetition of a `Debug.Log()` or `print()` function.

```
while(true)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

    Debug.Log("Coroutine Iteration Successful at " + Time.time.ToString() + "s");   
}
```

---

As you can see in the debug log, we now have scripted output appearing approximately every 3 seconds.

[image: My debug log, showing successful repeat WaitForSeconds() operation]

---

### The 'countdown' approach

I am going to address the proposed solution offered by *ardaozkal*, as in this particular case it would be a suitable alternative to using `WaitForSeconds()`. Consider the following code:

```
/// <summary>The time we wait between iterations of Debug.Log</summary>
public float time = 3;
/// <summary>Our current timer, counting down.</summary>
public float countdown = 3; 

void Update()
{
    countdown -= Time.deltaTime;   // Reduce our countdown by the
                                   // it has been since our last update

    if(countdownTimer <= 0)        // IF our countdown timer is below
                                   // 0, we have reached 3 seconds.
    {
        countdownTimer = time;              // Reset our countdown,

        Debug.Log("Print Iteration");       // print our output
    }
}
```

In this way, we can set up a 'countdown timer' to handle the same functionality. Every update, we subtract the time since the last update from our countdown. When countdown is at or below 0, we know that the set time has passed, and that that particular update should perform the timed print function. We then reset the countdown timer, using an alternate variable we store to remember the initial time.

---

This might be more suitable if you are unfamiliar with co-routines, but it does have its draw backs. Primarily, the functionality it offers is not anywhere near as extensive as the functionality offered by a co-routine. Further more, it can unnecessarily over-complicate your code, by requiring additional timers/variables.

Then again, you have to remember that co-routines are designed to run *alongside* your other code. They are more favorable for particular events you wish to occur *over* time, not so much *after a* time. You may find that in your scenario, you do not need to use co-routines at all, and this option would be easier to implement.

---

### More on Co-routines

If you are unfamiliar with co-routines, I would suggest you invest a little bit of time looking into them. While they can be abrasive, at times, they can also save you a lot of pain and suffering. You can find the **Unity manual entry on co-routines [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)**, and **some intermediate scripting tutorials on using co-routines [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines)**.

Comment: Dang, thorough answer. I can't beat that. :)

Comment: Here have a +1 man such detail much knowledge :D